# A debugger is attached to UWP.exe but not configured to handle this unhandle exception. | Combase.Pdb not loaded?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal

I am working on a xamarin Forms app and deploying it to UWP Local machine for testing purpose. It has a simple email checker form which calls an asp.net web api to verify if email exists in database. When I click on next button, debugger stops and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx8pg.png) exception is thrown.

I found its solution by going to debug property of uwp project and changing debugger type from managed to mixed. I applied changes, rebuild the project, deployed and another exception is raised this time which is shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEeC5.png) screenshot:

I have searched a lot about this on internet but I am unable to find its solution from past 4 days. Kindly review my code for this form and help me how to solve this issue. 
Here is the code for **GetUserEmailForm.Xaml:**

```
 <StackLayout Spacing="20" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="20">
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="What's Your Email Address" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Navy" />
    <Entry x:Name="txtEmail" Placeholder="Enter your Email" PlaceholderColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Button Text="Next" Clicked="Button_OnClicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Teal" WidthRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="indi" Color="Red" IsVisible="False" />
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the code for **GetUserEmailForm.Xaml.cs:**

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class GetUserEmailForm : ContentPage
{
    public Customer cust;
    public GetUserEmailForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        indi.IsVisible = true;
        var x = await PostData();
        indi.IsVisible = false;
    }

    public async Task<Customer> PostData()
    {
        cust.Email = txtEmail.Text;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:1214/api/PasswordReset", content);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //  isCreated = true;
                await DisplayAlert("Success", "Email found, We will send you a code to validate this Email." +
                                              " Please check your email and verify it on next screen.", "OK");
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return result;

            }
            else
            //if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Failed", "Email does not exist in the system.Try Again.", "OK");
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to check this code by putting a break point on the API calling line, but exceptions are raised even before hitting the break point. I 'll highly appreciate your precious comments. 
Thanks

Comment: Google "debugging 0xc000027b", lots of hits.

Comment: did you find any solution i got this error when implement azure push notifications

Answer (score 2):

Click on your UWP project, then go to Project > Properties...

This warning may appear if Visual Studio is configured to debug only managed exceptions and the exception you got is native. Go the the properties of your Project, to the Debug options, and change Debugger type from Managed Only to Mixed (Managed and Native).

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me unfortunately. It did seem to slow my app down a lot though, e.g. when starting up. I guess my issue is nothing to do with native.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are building your own executable that is using DCOM to activate a COM object, which resides in other executable -
 'PasswordReset.UWP.exe'.

To my understanding your COM client (code from the App you created) is calling method on the COM server object (in 'PasswordReset.UWP.exe'), and an internal exception occurs inside the process 'PasswordReset.UWP.exe'.

If this is correct then your way to debug it is to first attach a debugger to the COM server (PasswordReset.UWP.exe), and then run your app to create the exception. At this point you can debug the exception in 'PasswordReset.UWP.exe'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear #PazO, Thanks for your valuable words. Can you guide me on how to attach a debugger to COM Server? Is it all that I need to do ?

Comment: Hi #Ali Raza, First thing is to identify the process hosting the COM server. I assume here it is 'PasswordReset.UWP.exe'. Then use Visual Studio debugger or WinDBG debugger to attach to process and debug. If more information is needed on debugging please refer to external documentation of the selected debugger.

Comment: Hi sir, when i select uwp project as startup project and start debugging, a debugger is attached to 'PasswordReset.UWP.exe'. I checked this by navigating to Debug -> Attach to process. since, exception says detach the current debugger to handle this exception, I detached all the debuggers and then try to run application, it asks me to attach debugger from "New instance of Visual studio 2010". If i select it, it says "Invalid license data. Reinstall required". Still no progress :(

Comment: Hi #Ali Raza, it seems like you have some license issue with one of your software products. Unfortunately I will not be able to assist with this. The approach I offered would be the general debugging approach for COM client/server issues, where exception is being thrown on the server side.

Comment: Thanks Sir, should it work fine the way I tried to debug it i.e. by detaching a debugger if there was no license issue (I am gonna fix this issue soon) ? And if it worked fine, would I have to debug it always by detaching the debugger?

Comment: Hi #Ali Raza, I am not sure why you will need to detach debugger. You should attach a debugger *only* to the server side. Not client side. BTW - maybe the whole problem here is the license problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this we can take a temporary step which worked for me is opening the project in file explorer and delete the .vs folder. And this is for Visual studio 2017. Try it